# CompletionHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel, Object) in AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java

I write a chat room server using Java Asynchronous IO, here is the code:

```
class AcceptHandler
        implements CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Object> {

    private AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel;

    public AcceptHandler(AsynchronousServerSocketChannel sc) {
        this.serverChannel = sc;
    }

    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    @Override
    public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel sc, Object attachment) {
        AIOServer.channelList.add(sc);

        serverChannel.accept(null, this);
        sc.read(buff, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Object>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(Integer result, Object attachment) {
                System.out.println("there is a message");
                buff.flip();
                String content = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buff).toString();
                for (AsynchronousSocketChannel c : AIOServer.channelList) {
                    try {
                        c.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content.getBytes(AIOServer.UTF_8))).get();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                buff.clear();
                sc.read(buff, null, this);
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
                System.out.println("error: " + exc);

                AIOServer.channelList.remove(sc);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
        System.out.println("connect failed: " + exc);
    }
}
```

A client connects and this function will callback, several clients can chat with each other.But when a client closed, the client disconnected,"there is a message" will keep being printed,like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQCaB.png)

can someone give me an answer?

Comment: There is a recursive call ;  sc.read(buff, null, this) is invoked inside sc.read() , hence the issue.

Comment: but the sockectchannel in client has been closed, nothing to read

Comment: I guess still the recursive loop will be running until you get a SOE as there is no logic in place to exit/return if there is nothing to read.

Comment: function completed() will be callback only when read from IO successful,if no data ,it won't be callbacked

Comment: If you close the sever,same to client.I have found a solution,Integer result,if the connect closed, result < 0, and I close the channel on server manual